# Regular expressions - optional brackets

Tags: regex

I need a regex for this kind of input:

```
AB: EF
AB : EF
AB (CD): EF
AB (CD) XY: EF
```

I need 3 groups. One for the AB, second for the CD (if there isn't any, it could be empty), third for the EF.

How do I write such regex?

I tried:

```
(.*)?\s(\(.*\))\s?(.*)?:\s(.*)  --- AB: EF doesn't match
(.*)?\s?(\(.*\))\s?(.*)?:\s(.*)  --- AB (CD): EF has the second group is empty
```

Comment: show real examples, and add a tag for the language you use.

Comment: The example `AB (CD) XY: EF` doesn't match your description »I need 3 groups«. Should there be a match?

Comment: you need three groups then XY is for what???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in most regex engines, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/HxoXO6/1)

```
(\w{2}):? *(\((\w{2})\))?.*?: *(\w{2})
```

Replace `\w` with `\d` if you only want digits.

Group 1 matches `AB`, group 3 matches `CD`, group 4 matches `EF`.

- `(\w{2})` matches `AB`, any two alphanumeric characters.
- `:? *` matches optional `:` followed by any number of spaces.
- `(\((\w{2})\))?` matches optional `CD`, any two alphanumeric characters, inside parentheses.
- `.*?:` matches any character until next `:`.
- `*` matches any number of spaces after `:`.
- `(\w{2})` matches `EF`, any two alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
(\w+) ?(?:\(?(\w{2})\)?.*)?: (\w*)
```

This does exactly what you need. Proof: https://regex101.com/r/1TlGy9/1

As you said you needed 3 groups, I assumed you just wanted to have the ' XY' part as optional in other words: you don't want to match it but you want the other groups to match even if it is present.

Comment: One thing to be careful with is that this will match on broken parentheses if that's a requirement for you. ie: `AB (CD: EF` or `AB CD): EF`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`\w*\s?(\(.*\))?\s?\w*:\s?\w*`

This also can be applied.

Thanks

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cQeRhO/1

Hey there, as you can see in the Match information on the right hand side of the screen, this regular expression does not give the right groups. I wanted to check your solution because it looked a lot cleaner than mine, but unfortunately it does not do what the question asks.